# Scala: Swapping the case of each character in a string

Tags: scala

Using Scala I want to take a sub string of an initial string and swap each characters case so that capital letters become lower case lower case become upper.

```
var swapCase = buffer.substring(lwr, upr).to?OTHER?Case
```

I have used the .toUpperCase and .toLowerCase commands in the past and was wondering if there is a similar command for just swapping case without having to iterate through each character within a loop and evaluating which operation needs to be performed on each character i.e:

```
if(char(x).isUpperCase){char(x).toLowerCase}

else if(char(x).isLowerCase){char(x).toUpperCase}
```

In short, is there a really quick way to do this with a "." command instead of writing multiple lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is about as good as you are going to get:

```
def swapCase(s: String): String =
  s.map(ch => if (ch.isLower) ch.toUpper else ch.toLower)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the Tim's oneliner could be:

```
def swapCharCase(ch: Char) = if (ch.isLower) ch.toUpper else ch.toLower

def swapCase(s: String): String = s.map(swapCharCase)
```

I find it a tiny bit more readable - and perhaps `swapCharCase` may become handy anyway.

To use it as `.swapCase` as requested, use an `implicit` class instead to provide the extension method:

```
implicit class CaseStringOps(s: String) {
  def swapCase: String = s.map(swapCharCase)

}
```